# How big a "scaffold" does second-order logic need to detect its own equivalence notion?

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory, second-order-logic

*(Now asked [at MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/417051/how-big-a-scaffold-does-second-order-logic-need-to-detect-its-own-equivalence).)*

Let $\Sigma$ be the language consisting of a single binary relation symbol. Second-order logic can "detect" second-order-elementary-equivalence of $\Sigma$-structures in the following sense:

> There is a finite language $\Sigma'\supseteq \Sigma\sqcup\{X,Y\}$, with $X,Y$ unary relation symbols and a $\Sigma'$-sentence $\eta$ such that for all $\Sigma$-structures $\mathfrak{A},\mathfrak{B}$ the following are equivalent:
>
> - $\mathfrak{A}\equiv_{\mathsf{SOL}}\mathfrak{B}$.
> - There is an $\mathfrak{M}\models\eta$ with $X^\mathfrak{M}\upharpoonright\Sigma\cong\mathfrak{A}$ and $Y^\mathfrak{M}\upharpoonright\Sigma\cong\mathfrak{B}$.

Roughly speaking, we just "piggyback" on the analogous result (via Fraisse's theorem) for first-order logic, using the facts that $(i)$ powersethood is second-order definable and $(ii)$ second-order-equivalence amounts to first-order-equivalence of "powerstructures." However, this results in some significant blow-up: the witnessing $\mathfrak{M}$ for a pair of countable $\mathsf{SOL}$-equivalent structures will have size continuum.

I'm curious if we can do better. Let the **scaffold number for second-order logic** be the smallest cardinal $\xi$ with the following property:

> There is a finite language $\Sigma'\supseteq \Sigma\sqcup\{X,Y\}$, with $X,Y$ unary relation symbols and a $\Sigma'$-sentence $\eta$ such that for all $\color{red}{\mbox{countable}}$ $\Sigma$-structures $\mathfrak{A},\mathfrak{B}$ the following are equivalent:
>
> - $\mathfrak{A}\equiv_{\mathsf{SOL}}\mathfrak{B}$.
> - There is an $\mathfrak{M}\models\eta$ with $\color{red}{\vert\mathfrak{M}\vert<\xi}$ and $X^\mathfrak{M}\upharpoonright\Sigma\cong\mathfrak{A}$ and $Y^\mathfrak{M}\upharpoonright\Sigma\cong\mathfrak{B}$.

Trivially we have $\omega_1\le\xi\le\mathfrak{c}^+$. Meanwhile, assuming $\mathsf{V=L}$ we have that $\equiv_\mathsf{SOL}$ and $\cong$ coincide for countable structures, so $\omega_1=\xi=\mathfrak{c}<\mathfrak{c}^+$ is also consistent.

Beyond this, however, not much is clear to me. In particular, I'm curious whether $\xi$ can be small even if the continuum is large and we have large cardinals:

> Is it consistent with $\mathsf{ZFC}$ + a proper class of Woodins *(although I'm not wedded to that specifically)* that $\omega_1=\xi<\mathfrak{c}$?